# troubleshooting "pseudo-hashes are deprecated"  while using xml module

Tags: perl, hash

I am just learning how to use perl hashes and ran into this message in perl.  I am using `XML::Simple` to parse xml output and using `exists` to check on the hash keys.

**Message:**
`Pseudo-hashes are deprecated at ./h2.pl line 53.
Argument "\x{2f}\x{70}..." isn't numeric in exists at ./h2.pl line 53.
Bad index while coercing array into hash at ./h2.pl line 53.`

I had the script **working** earlier with one test directory and then executed the script on another directory for testing when I got this message. How do I resolve/workaround this?

**Code that the error references:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

#my $data = XMLin($xml);
my $data = XMLin($xml, ForceArray => [qw (file) ]);
my $size=0;

if (exists $data->{class}
       and $data->{class}=~ /FileNotFound/) {
        print "The directory: $Path does not exist\n";
        exit;
          } elsif (exists $data->{file}->{path}
                      and $data->{file}->{path} =~/test-out-00/) {
                    $size=$data->{file}->{size};
                       if ($size < 1024000) {
                          print "FILE SIZE:$size BYTES\n";
                          exit;
                       }
          } else {
            exit;
}

print Dumper( $data );
```

Working test case, data structure looks like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
              'recursive' => 'no',
              'version' => '0.20.202.1.1101050227',
              'time' => '2011-09-30T02:49:39+0000',
              'filter' => '.*',
              'file' => {
                        'owner' => 'test_act',
                        'replication' => '3',
                        'blocksize' => '134217728',
                        'permission' => '-rw-------',
                        'path' => '/source/feeds/customer/test/test-out-00',
                        'modified' => '2011-09-30T02:48:41+0000',
                        'size' => '135860644',
                        'group' => '',
                        'accesstime' => '2011-09-30T02:48:41+0000'
                     'modified' => '2011-09-30T02:48:41+0000'
                   },
      'exclude' => ''
    };
recursive:no
version:0.20.202.1.1101050227
time:2011-10-01T07:06:16+0000
filter:.*
file:HASH(0x84c83ec)
path:/source/feeds/customer/test
directory:HASH(0x84c75d8)
exclude:
```

**Data structure with seeing error:**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'recursive' => 'no',
          'version' => '0.20.202.1.1101050227',
          'time' => '2011-10-03T04:49:36+0000',
          'filter' => '.*',
          'file' => [
                    {
                      'owner' => 'test_act',
                      'replication' => '3',
                      'blocksize' => '134217728',
                      'permission' => '-rw-------',
                      'path' => '/source/feeds/customer/test/20110531/test-out-00',
                      'modified' => '2011-10-03T04:47:46+0000',
                      'size' => '121406618',
                      'group' => 'feeds',
                      'accesstime' => '2011-10-03T04:47:46+0000'
                    },
```

Test xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><listing time="2011-10-03T04:49:36+0000" recursive="no" path="/source/feeds/customer/test/20110531" exclude="" filter=".*" version="0.20.202.1.1101050227"><directory path="/source/feeds/customer/test/20110531" modified="2011-10-03T04:48:19+0000" accesstime="1970-01-01T00:00:00+0000" permission="drwx------" owner="test_act" group="feeds"/><file path="/source/feeds/customer/test/20110531/test-out-00" modified="2011-10-03T04:47:46+0000" accesstime="2011-10-03T04:47:46+0000" size="121406618" replication="3" blocksize="134217728" permission="-rw-------" owner="test_act" group="feeds"/><file path="/source/feeds/customer/test/20110531/test-out-01" modified="2011-10-03T04:48:04+0000" accesstime="2011-10-03T04:48:04+0000" size="127528522" replication="3" blocksize="134217728" permission="-rw-------" owner="test_act" group="feeds"/><file path="/source/feeds/customer/test/20110531/test-out-02" modified="2011-10-03T04:48:19+0000" accesstime="2011-10-03T04:48:19+0000" size="125452919" replication="3" blocksize="134217728" permission="-rw-------" owner="test_act" group="feeds"/></listing>
```

Comment: Did you edit the output? I don't see how XML::Simple could produce that output without `ForceArray => [qw( file )]` which you didn't use. Was there more than one `file`?

Comment: yes, sorry. the output was too large. i had to cut and paste. i was trying to highlight the fact, that it is `nested`. looks like that is what i need to look into. thanks

Comment: Then you should be using `ForceArray => [qw( file )]`. The next question is: What is your program suppose to do when there is more than one file, cause right now it assumes there is only one file.

Comment: You might also like to read [this article](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=218480) for avoiding other common pitfalls with XML::Simple.  I really recommend XML::LibXML for all but the most trivial scripts

Comment: @ikegami - I added an xml file. What I want to do with my program is look for one file only labeled as `/source/feeds/customer/test/test-out-00`amongst a list of files. If that file doesn't exist, exit the program. Should I be using `XML::Simple` for this? I did add `my $data = XMLin($xml, ForceArray => [qw (file) ]);` but still same error mesg.

Comment: @jdamae, Yes, with ForceArray, you get the error even in the case that used to "work", since your code is misisng a loop to look at all files. I never use XML::Simple. It's the most complex XML parser to use. I use much faster XML::LibXML. Now that you added ForceArray, the problem has nothing to do with the XML parser but with your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Pseudo-hashes are deprecated" error means you're trying to access an array as a hash, which means that either `$data->{file}` or `$data->{file}{path}` is an arrayref.

You can check the data type by using `print ref $data->{file}`. The `Data::Dumper` module may also help you to see what is in your data structure (perhaps while setting `$Data::Dumper::Maxdepth = N` to limit the dump to N number of levels if the structure is big).

**UPDATE**

Now that you are using ForceArray, `$data->{file}` should always point to an arrayref, which may possibly have multiple references to `path`. Here is a modified segment of your code to handle that. But note that the logic of the `if-then-exit` conditions may have to change.

```
if (defined $data->{class} and $data->{class}=~ /FileNotFound/) {
    print "The directory: $Path does not exist\n";
    exit;
}

exit if ! defined $data->{file};

# filter the list for the first file entry named test-out-00
my ( $file ) = grep { 
    defined $_->{path} && $_->{path} =~ /test-out-00/ 
} @{ $data->{file} };

exit if ! defined $file;

$size = $file->{size};
if ($size < 1024000) {
    print "FILE SIZE:$size BYTES\n";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: when using `ref`, would I remove the `exists` keyword? Also, how I print out maxdepth? I've used this before with dumper. `print Dumper ($data);`

Comment: I added my dumper output for reference. I see a slight difference in the structure (see edit)

Answer (score 2):

When using [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aSimple), the `ForceArray` option is one of the most important to understand, especially in cases when your input data has nested elements that can occur 1 or more times. For example:

```
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my @xml_snippets = (
    '<opt> <name x="3" y="4">B</name> <name x="5" y="6">C</name> </opt>',
    '<opt> <name x="1" y="2">A</name>                            </opt>',
);

for my $xs (@xml_snippets){
    my $data = XMLin($xs, ForceArray => 0);
    print Dumper($data);
}
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'name' => [      # Array ref because there are 2 <name> elements.
    {
      'y' => '4',
      'content' => 'B',
      'x' => '3'
    },
    {
      'y' => '6',
      'content' => 'C',
      'x' => '5'
    }
  ]
};
$VAR1 = {
  'name' => {      # No intermediate array ref.
    'y' => '2',
    'content' => 'A',
    'x' => '1'
  }
};
```

By activating the `ForceArray` option, you can direct [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aSimple) to produce consistent data structures that always use the intermediate array reference, even when there is only 1 of a particular nested element. You can activate the option globally or for specific tags, as illustrated here:

```
my $data = XMLin($xs, ForceArray => 1                );  # Globally.
my $data = XMLin($xs, ForceArray => [qw(name foo bar)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend that you use `ForceArray => [qw( file )]` as previously discussed. That will cause an array to be returned for `file`, whether there's one or more `file` element. This is easier to handle than having two possible formats.

As I previously indicated, the problem is that you made no provision for looping over multiple `file` elements. You said you wanted to exit if the file doesn't exist, so that means you want

```
my $found;
for my $file (@{ $data->{file} }) {
   if ($file->{path} =~ m{/test-out-00\z}) {
      $found = $file;
      last;
   }
}

die("Test file not found\n") if !$found;

... do something with file data in $found ...
```